Importing a section from another document (with begin document)
I have two different latex files, which I would like to import one to another file. Here's what I've searched previously in older posts.

This one
Another one

To understand my case, I provide the following MWE as a brief overview. (Let say, I want to import second file into first file) :

First File

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

% --> I want to import section 'A Content' in the second file

\end{document}


Second File

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
    \section{A Content}
         This is a following example math as $x^2$.
\end{document}

Is it possible to import a section in the second file, if each file is mentioned as in MWE above? Also, should one provide all the packages required to import (i.e., I should mention all the packages I used in the first file, in order to call/import the section in second file)?

If the section is the entire body of the second file, it is easy. If you have a bunch of stuff before \section and after $x^2$., it is not. So taking your question literally, the answer is there's no problem since the second file 'as is' contains nothing else in its body. But if your actual case is different, well, things are then different.

Well, most of my cases do only require me to import all sections. Would the solution be different if I'd like to import, say chapters?

As long as you want everything between \begin{document} and \end{document}, it doesn't matter what it is. Sections, chapters, parts, paragraphs, pictures ... as long as you want everything, it's easy. What would be hard would be if you wanted, say, one chapter from a file which contained two.

Taking your question literally, it is easy because the section of the second file you want corresponds to the entire body of the document. So you could use import or standalone to include it.
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{standalone}

\begin{document}

% \includestandalone{<filename>}
\input{<filename>}

\end{document}

If you use \includestandalone{}, you can use the subpreambles option and standalone will merge the preambles of all included documents. If you don't use that option, you need to ensure any needed packages are loaded in the main document's preamble.

There are some packages that help with this, notably standalone or subfiles but they all have some constraints and I think it's simpler to manage the shared code directly, which gives you full control over how to merge package loading etc.
Put the shared parts in separate files (these may be sections, or chapters or just individual tables or paragraphs) so here
shared1.tex
 \section{A Content}
         This is a following example math as $x^2$.

Then your first file is
document1.tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

% --> I want to import section 'A Content' in the second file
\input{shared1}

\end{document}

and your second file is
document2.tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}
\input{shared1}
\end{document}

